# jQuery selector syntax question

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Here is my html:

```
<form>
    <dl>
        <dt>&nbsp;</dt>
        <dd><input type="hidden"></dd>

        <dt>Dont hide this one</dt>
        <dd><input type="text"></dd>
    </dl>
</form>
```

I'm using jQuery to hide the `dt`/`dd` elements where the input type is hidden with this code:

```
$("input[type=hidden]").each(function() {
    $(this).parent().hide().prev().hide();
});
```

But I also only want to apply this to `dt`s where the text is `&nbsp;`. How can I do this sort of select?

**Update:** Maybe I need to clarify: A few people have posted answers where it hides the dd before checking if the content of the dt is also `&nbsp;`. Both conditions must be true before hiding both the dt and dd.

**Final Solution:** Here's what I ended up with:

```
$('input[type=hidden]').filter(function() {
    return $(this).closest('dd').prev('dt').html() === '&nbsp;';
}).each(function() {
    $(this).closest('dd').hide()
           .prev('dt').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("input[type=hidden]").filter(function() {
    return $(this).parent().prev('dt').html() === "&nbsp;";
}).each(function() {
    $(this).parent().hide().prev().hide();
});
```

This will not select `<dt>foo&nbsp;bar</dt>`

which `contains('&nbsp;')` would.

More concisely (with credit to [Emil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875807/jquery-selector-syntax-question/1875828#1875828))

```
$("input[type=hidden]").filter(function() {
    return $(this).closest('dd').prev('dt').html() === "&nbsp;";
}).closest('dd').hide().prev('dt').hide();
```

Comment: As people have already reposted answers... and I can't comment yet cobbal's code is missing this: $("input[type=hidden]").each(function() { $(this).parent().hide().prev().filter(function() { return $(this).html() === "&nbsp;"; }).hide();
}); return

Comment: this doesn't work. it hides the dd before checking if the content of the dt is also &nbsp;. Both conditions must be true before hiding both the dt and dd.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood what you were trying to do. Updated now

Answer (score 1):

Use the [contains](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/contains#text) selector:

`$("dt:contains('&nbsp;')").hide();`

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[type=hidden]").each(function() {
    $(this).closest('dd').hide()
           .prev('dt').hide();
});
```

This code finds the closest parent of the input with tag `dd`, hides it, then looks for a `dt` sibling and hides it as well.

Answer (score 0):

The contains selector doesn't match the whole content, so it might work for you, but is not an ideal solution. The correct way to do this is to use the filter function:

```
$('input[type=hidden]').filter(function() {
   return $(this).prev().html() == '&nbsp;'
})
.each(function() {
   $(this).hide();
   $(this).prev().hide();
});
```

Comment: this doesn't work. it end up hiding the entire dl. I am only trying to hide the dt and dd where the dt contains &nbsp; and the dd contains a hidden form element.

Comment: Oh, I didn't unterstand the question correct, I'm sorry. I changed the code now.

Answer (score 0):

This also does the trick (adapted from an earlier version of cobbal's answer):

```
$("input[type=hidden]").each(function() {
    if ($(this).parent().prev().filter(function() {
        return $(this).html() === "&nbsp;";
    }).hide().length > 0) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't think an empty jQuery set evaluates to false, wouldn't the if statement always execute?